# Java regular expression returning false on match

Tags: java

I am basically trying to filter file names that end with .ack.gz

e.g. String filename = "somefile.ack.gz"

```
return filename.matches(".ack.gz$");  returns false
return filename.matches("\\.ack\\.gz$");  returns false
```

Shouldn't one of these match?  Not sure what I have missed here...

Comment: The string doesn't match either of those regular expressions. Your inclusion of `$` suggests you want to test if *part* of the string matches the regular expression, which is not what `matches` tests. Why not just use the `endsWith` method?

Comment: Adding `.*` on the front should help.  And the `$` on the end is unnecessary because `matches` will always try to match the entire string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `String.matches` method ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String))) tests to see if the regex matches the entire target string.

But in your example, the regex `".ack.gz$"` does not match all of the characters of `"somefile.ack.gz"`.  Therefore match returns `false`.

If you really want to use a regex to do this, then your code should be:

```
return filename.matches(".*\\.ack\\.gz");
```

Notes:

1. The `.*` matches the first part of the filename.
2. The `\\.` says to match a literal `.` character.  If you have no escaping then `.` matches any single character.  A double escape is required because the pattern is being expressed as a Java string literal.
3. Leading `^` and trailing `$` are unnecessary.  They are *implied* by the semantics of `match`.

---

But as @kaya points out, it would be better to use `String.endsWith` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String))) here since you don't need regex functionality for this test.

Answer (score 0):

`Matches` returns `true` the specified regular expression matches the entire target string.  It won't return `true` if the expression only matches part of the string.  So to use `matches`, you want to supply an expression that matches the whole filename.  In your case, that would be:

```
return filename.matches(".*\\.ack\\.gz");  returns false
```

The `.*` at the front of the expression matches anything at the front of the string that isn't matched by the rest of the expression, so that the expression will match the entire target string.

You don't need the `$` because the expression already has to match to the end of the string, and so it's redundant.